# Как автоматически привязывать префаб в Unity какому-либо объекту?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Суть в том, что у меня есть кнопка при нажатии на которую должно появляется предупреждение, о том "Уверены ли в своем выборе?" и ответы да нет. Так вот сначала я просто сделал предупреждение как UI(2D-приложение) элемент и при нажатии на кнопку он алерт просто активируется на сцене, все бы нечего, но если сделать несколько кнопок, у которых должно появляться это предупреждение, то при нажати на другую кнопку появляется алерт и после выбора ответа да, срабатывает не та на которую изначально нажимал, а самая первая! Решил делать это не через отдельный объект на сцене, а с помощью префаба алерта, то есть просто его спавнить при нажатии на кнопку, но проблема в том, что префаб сам по себе не определяется(если что кнопка и алерт префабы). Помогите решить!!!

Answer (score 1):

Ничего ни к чему привязывать не нужно это ошибка. Прифабу должно быть пофиг кто и как его использует.

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]

public class Confirm : MonoBehaviour { // скрипт для вашего префаба

    public event Action<bool> Confirmed; // событие выбора
    [SerializeField] private Button[] _buttons; // указываем кнопки в инспекторе

    public void Choise (bool result) { // в OnClick кнопак указываем эту функцию с true и false
        Confirmed?.Invoke(result);
        DisableButtons();
    }

    private void DisableButtons () {
        foreach (Button button in _buttons)
            button.interactable = false;
    }
}
```

---

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]

public class Foo : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] private Confirm _confirmTemplate; // ссылка на префаб
    private Confirm _confirm;

    public void Start () {
        _confirm = Instantiate(_confirmTemplate.gameObject, transform).GetComponent<Confirm>();
        _confirm.Confirmed += Confirm; // подписываемся на событие
    }

    public void Confirm (bool result) {
        // не забываем отписаться!
        _confirm.Confirmed -= Confirm;
        if (result) {

        } else {

        }
    }
}
```