# Как получить доступ к конкретному дочернему объекту в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-ui

Смысл в том, что у меня есть объект к которому прикреплены(дочерние объекты) две кнопки("да", "нет"). Мне нужно через скрипт обращаться к этим кнопкам, следовательно я создал две переменные("yes","no") с типом Button. Каждая переменная должна хранить в себе доступ к соответственной себе кнопке. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1271083/Как-автоматически-привязывать-префаб-в-unity-какому-либо-объекту/1271126#1271126

Answer (score 1):

```
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Foo : MonoBehaviour 
{
    // указываем сслыки на кнопки в инспекторе
    [SerializeField] private Button _buttonYes;
    [SerializeField] private Button _buttonNo;
}
```

Но смысла в этом нет, [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1271083/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B1-%D0%B2-unity-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83/1271126#1271126) как это делается.